# Elementary Question

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

Let be $f:X\to X$ a  bijection, an $A\subset X$  a  invariant  subset of $X$, i.e
$f(A)\subset A.$ How can see that

$$f(A)=A$$

I'm trying to show that
$$f(A^{c})\subset A^c$$

but I can not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The claim is false. For example, let $X=\mathbb{Z}$, let $f(n)=n+1$, and let $A=\mathbb{N}$. Then $f(A)=\mathbb{N} \setminus \{ 0 \} \subsetneq A$.

Comment: Snap! :-) $\qquad$

Answer (score 4):

The statement is false. Let $X=\Bbb Z$ and $f(n)=n+1$ for $n\in X$. Then $\Bbb N$ is $f$-invariant, but its complement is not.